# Find a composition of a linear transformation and function in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This is part of a larger problem, but I am trying to find $T \circ f(\vec{x})$, using the facts that:

$T(\vec{x})=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 5\\0 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 &0 \end{bmatrix}\vec{x}$

$f(x,y,z)=(x+y+z,2x+2z,-x-y-z)$.

Therefore the matrix corresponding to $f$ that I found is is
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\2 & 0 & 2 \\  -1 & -1 &-1 \end{bmatrix}$.

How do I combine these facts to find the composition? Could I convert $T$ to a function to obtain $t(x,y,z)=(x+5z,3y+2z,y)$ and follow from there?

Comment: Do you know matrix multiplication?

Comment: Just a few recommendations, not that you're necessarily wrong: From what I've seen, composition is usually notated as $(T\circ f)(\vec x)$, $[T\circ f](\vec x)$, or $T(f(\vec x))$. Also, if functions map to certain objects, you will want to reflect that in how the function's name is typeset—for example, $\vec f$ or $\bf f$ for vectors, $\bf T$ or $\boldsymbol T$ for tensors or matrices—but you need to be consistent, and your notation needs to reflect how you're distinguishing (or assimilating) the objects.